# Android - Weird Runtime Exception Found on Crashlytics

Tags: android, crashlytics, runtimeexception

so today i was checking my Crashlytics and found Application is Been crashed 88 times but couldn't find the source 
Here is the Exception Detail

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.f.f.a()' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3003)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3064)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1659)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)
```

Comment: When we Using Pro-guard rules, then all class name and variable name changed.

Comment: Hi, Paul from Crashlytics here. Have you followed our guide on configuring ProGuard and DexGuard? If not, you may see obfuscated errors like the one you posted: https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/dex-and-proguard.html.

Comment: updated the build with the proguard rules thanks paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you release an Apk file, you can define a path for mapping file which generate by pro-guard. Then you can use it to de-obfuscate com.example.f.f.a() and find location of error.